# Get the prop and value of dynamically added inputs using redux with react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

There are two input fields in my form initially. But I've a button to add the fields if required. I've used redux and I'm having difficulty on getting the state of each 
each inputs of the form since the inputs are added dynamically by user. How can I pass the different props with the respective value to the action and get those value back
from reducer?

SignUp.js

```
import SignUpUserInfo from './Common/SignUpUserInfo';

var index = 0;
class SignUp extends React.Component {

  state = {
    myArr: [],
  }

  _onPressOut() {
    let temp = index ++
    this.state.myArr.push(temp)
    this.setState({
        myArr: this.state.myArr
    })
   }

  render() {
    if (this.state.myArr.length < 1) {
      let temp = index;
      this.state.myArr.push(temp);
      this.setState({
          myArr: this.state.myArr,
      });
    }

    let Arr = this.state.myArr.map((a, i) => {
      return <SignUpUserInfo key={i} {...this.props} />;
    });

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={[{ backgroundColor: '#E9E9E9' }]}>
          { Arr }
          <View style={CommonStyle.bottomGap}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressOut()}>
              <Text>Register more people</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={CommonStyle.horizontalGap}>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              this.signUpFunction();
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 10, }}>
              <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Sign Up</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { Name, Designation } = state.Auth; //how to get name & designation for multiple people here?
  return { Name, Designation, };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { AuthGet })(SignUp);
```

SignUpUserInfo.js  //includes required inputs

```
render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={'Enter Your Name'}
          onChangeText={text => {
             //'Name' prop should be different for different input.How to do that?
            this.onNameChange(`Name`, text);
          }}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder={'Designation'}
          onChangeText={text => {
            this.onDesignationChange(`Designation`, text);
            }
          }
          value={this.state.SignUpDesignation}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUpUserInfo;
```

Action

```
export const AuthGet = ({prop, value}) => {
  return ({
    type: SIGN_UP_GET,
    payload: {prop, value},
  });
};
```

Reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  Name: '',
  Designation: '',
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, actions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case SIGN_UP_GET:
      return { ...state, [actions.payload.prop]: actions.payload.value};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create state inside reducer as an array.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  users: []
};
```

and Inside reducer function push an object with empty name and designation every time a new user is added.

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, actions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case "ADD_USER":
      return { ...state, users: [...state.users, {name: '', designation: ''}]};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

call `dispatch({ type: "ADD_USER" })` inside `_onPressOut` function.

After that you need an action that updates state according to index

```
function updatePersonStateFor(index, key, andValue) {
   return {
      type: "UPDATE_STATE_FOR_INDEX",
      payload: { index, key, value: andValue },
   }
}
```

Inside reducer add an case

```
... // reducer

case "UPDATE_STATE_FOR_INDEX":
return {
    users: [
        ...state.users.slice(0, action.payload.index),
        {
            ...state.users[action.payload.index],
            [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value
        },
        ...state.users.slice(action.payload.index + 1),
    ]
}
```

Inside this code I am copying all elements before index and after index. In the current index copy all existing elements and update action.payload.value for given action.payload.key